# Wrong mutt smtp server from Motion

Tags: email, motion, mutt

I'm using Motion to manage a camera and it works perfectly.
I've configured mutt so it can send emails when an event occur on the camera.
When I send an email via mutt by myself it works every times.
But when it's motion that send the email, the "from:" field is not good and it doesn't send the email. Do you know why ? I've configured my `~/.muttrc` file and it works when I do it without motion.

my `~/.muttrc` :

```
# Name of expeditor
set realname = "Camera"

# Activate TLS if available on the server
set ssl_starttls=yes

# Always use SSL for connection to the server
set ssl_force_tls=yes

# Configuration of imap (Only if you want to be able to read emails on the Pi)
#set spoolfile=imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/
#set imap_user = "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
#set imap_pass = "PASSWORD"

# Configuration SMTP
set smtp_url = "smtp://[MY_EMAIL]@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "[MY_PASSWD]"
set from = "[MY_EMAIL]"
set use_envelope_from=yes

# Local info, date 
#set locale="fr_FR" 
set date_format="%A %d %b %Y à %H:%M:%S (%Z)" 
#set locale="iso-8859-15"
```

Normal "sent" file (when I do it without Motion) :

```
From john.smith@gmail.com Wed May  2 07:28:59 2018
Date: Wed, 2 May 2018 07:28:59 +0000
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Camera <john.smith@gmail.com>
To: john.smith@gmail.com
Subject: Test
Message-ID: <20180502072859.qhqyhfwcs5nw7quj@RPi>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
User-Agent: NeoMutt/20170113 (1.7.2)
Status: RO
Content-Length: 2
Lines: 1
```

Wrong "sent" file (when I do it with Motion) :

```
From motion@RPi Wed May  2 07:17:07 2018
Date: Wed, 2 May 2018 07:17:07 +0000
From: motion@RPi
To: john.smith@gmail.com
Subject: Picture
Message-ID: <20180502071707.nx7asct4m2hds6vt@RPi>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
User-Agent: NeoMutt/20170113 (1.7.2)
Status: RO
Content-Length: 39
Lines: 1
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you very much

A.